# If interfaces do not have constructors, then is Object class super class of an interface?

Tags: java, class, interface, super

I read that interfaces do not have a constructors, which means it will not call super() of its super class. I also read that each and every class in Java is a subclass of `Object`

What about an interface, is it subclass of Object? Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it's not. An interface cannot be instantiated to form an object, it is **not** a class.

Comment: r u sure about **interface cannot be instantiated**? then what about anonymous class?

Comment: @Quoi: As you have said yourself, anonymous class -- an anonymous  implementation of some interface.

Answer (score 1):

No interface is  a subclass of Object class, since interface cannot extend a class whether implicit or explicit.

Reason for constructor is to create an instance, since interface cannot be instantiated as they don't provide any functionality they are just a contract only class can be instantiated hence they have constructor.

Answer (score 1):

**An interface is a named collection of method definitions (without implementations). An interface can also include constant declarations.**

Interface and class have some basic difference and one of them is do not have a constructors. Actually interface does not made for it and you cannot instantiate interface but there is way you can still instantiate interface.

```
interface Interface{
     abstract String fun();
 }

Interface interfc=new Interface() {
    @Override
    public String fun() {
        return super.toString();
    }
};

Type type=interfc.getClass();
```

Here interface has been instantiated as anonymous class.But still you cannot place  constructor here according to java language specification. But still you can use `super` class Which will be immediately super class of this anonymous class.

```
An anonymous class cannot have an explicitly declared constructor.
```

And there is alternative solution of this that is using final variable in super class.

Answer (score 0):

While some people suggest thinking of interfaces as "can-do" rather than "is-a" relationships, I think it's more helpful to think of them "is a __er" or "is a __able thing".  To use a real-world analogy, a book (dead-tree edition), a bound paper magazine, a newspaper, a promotional advertising flyer, a sign, and a scrap of paper with some words written on it, are all "readable things".  If someone were to show another person a book and ask "Is this a readable thing", the answer would be that it is.  On the other hand, if someone were to show another person a book and ask "What is this?" the response would not be "A readable thing", but more likely "A book", or perhaps "A hardcover fifth-printing copy of the second U.S. edition of the novel 'Great Expectations' by Charles Dickens".  Any type of "readable thing" has some identity beyond merely being a "readable thing".

Likewise with Java interfaces.  An object may implement an arbitrary number of interfaces, but every object must have a type in addition to the set of interfaces it supports.  Note that it is possible to define a method which will return a new object of unknown type that implements an interface; that would be equivalent to asking someone, "Please get me something to read" without specifying what type of object was desired.  Such a method could select a type of object to return, and give the caller one which is "readable".  Constructors, however, unlike general methods, require the caller to specify precisely what type of object is desired.  Merely specifying that an object is "readable" would not be a sufficient specification.

Answer (score 0):

No interface can not have constructor. Because interface support multiple inheritance. That means if a class inherit two interface then due to constructor chaining there will be ambiguity which constructor will be called from class constructor.